# Div transition triggered by a tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am playing around with this fiddle I found which is really close to what I am trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/5N3YK/20/

The only thing is that when I try to change the `section` tags to `div` tags it breaks, and also I want the div's to **fade instead of slide**.

Help is always greatly appreciated!

Comment: Almost all the JS code there is about sliding appropriately.  So I'm not sure your "really close" is really close...

Comment: And what do you mean by " when I try to change the tags to tags"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UDt7q/11/ - when you're changing `section` to `div` you've to update your JS and CSS too

Comment: Sorry... fixed my post.  I had html tags in there so obviously they wouldnt show up.

Comment: `I want the div's to fade instead of slide.` What about: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ ?

Comment: When I change the section tags to divs, everything still works: http://jsfiddle.net/UDt7q/12/

Comment: @RobertTaylor check out my answer, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try - http://jsfiddle.net/UDt7q/21/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.Fader = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            $('a').bind('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $( "#hello div" ).fadeOut();
                $( "#hello div" + $(this).attr('href') ).fadeIn();
            })
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: BTW `.bind()` is deprecated. You might want to use `.on()` - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

**Updated fiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/UDt7q/22/

Comment: I guess this is what you were asking about. Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. but the fiddle I was using is different from the one you posted.  I want my first div to be visible on load

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/5N3YK/23/

I changed the functionality of the code to hide the `div`s rather than push them off the page, but the idea is the same.

`section`s are now `div`s and they fade rather than slide.

Answer (score -1):

To make something "appear", you can use

```
$('.selector').fadeIn();
```

from Jquery. Similarly, you can show(), hide(), fadeOut()